# Extracting Numbers from Yahoo Financial statement, willing to pay some money through Pay Pal

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to extract financial data from yahoo finance using python.
Below there is a link to an image that shows in circles which data I am trying to retrieve. It has the organization of the data table however I do not know where to begin with the givens shown in the picture.

This is the image of the code location of the numbers I'm trying to extract from yahoo finance, with the table name and td tickers.

[image]

I realize that I must somehow use the td tickers to find the numbers that I need for the extraction however Im not sure what are the basics commands that I need to implement.

This is a [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/gv/financials?ltr=1) to an example of the the data table that I'm trying to scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you scraped is rendered by JavaScript, requests and urllib can not handle JavaScript. I recommend you using selenium and BeautifulSoup to extract data.
This is when JavaScript is disabled:
[image]

the data you wanted is in this url :

```
http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=378724&callback=jsonp1482077238548&_=1482077239651
```

i put it in the bs4, you can get the data by you own:

```
import requests, bs4, json

r = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=378724&callback=jsonp1482077238548&_=1482077239651')

js = r.text.strip('jsonp1482077238548()')
html_str = json.loads(js)['result']
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'lxml')
```

out:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="baseline" style="display:none">
   <div>
    156508000000
   </div>
   <div>
    170910000000
   </div>
   <div>
    182795000000
   </div>
   <div>
    233715000000
   </div>
   <div>
    215639000000
   </div>
   <div>
    215639000000
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left ">
   <div class="r_xcmenu rf_table_left">
    <div class="rf_header ">
     <div class="lbl " currency="USD" fiscalyearend="September" fyenumber="9" id="unitsAndFiscalYear">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rf_crow1" id="label_i1" style="_height:16px; _float:none;">
     <div class="lbl">
      Revenue
     </div>
     <div class="chart_contain_free" id="chart_i1">
      <div class="chart_icon">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I wish there could be some checkbox to check when posting beautifulsoup questions that would say something like _[x] I understand that requests+bs cannot be used to scrape elements that are dynamically loaded with javascript and I have made sure that is not the case. PS: If that is the case, I'll use selenium first._

Comment: post the html code and the data form you want so i can write code for you

Comment: Isn't the html code found in the inspect page option on a page? If you can help scrape the numbers I need I am willing to pay you some money through pay pal

Comment: yes, i see the comment and i ignore it, the reason is in stack overflow, my only concern is: how to solve the problem, and the repu i made. if you update the question, yes, i will help you. I try to visit the web, and it failed, i think my network is unstable. so, i can not help you here.  if you want to get help, just post a question, not post  paypal.

Comment: Oh ok sorry about that..Does this webpage work with your network? http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=aapl&ops=clear

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when I get home tonight

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask you how you got the http link that is inside the request.get() and the jsonp1482077238548() inside the text.strip(). I'm hoping to automate the program where all I do is change the Stock ticker so that I can access their data..Is there a way that you know where I can just read a list of stock tickers and the link in the request .get() updates automatically? And I apologize that I am completely new to programming, but Is there anyway you could show me an example of how to put the numbers we scrapped into a matrix? for instance putting the Revenue row into a matrix

Comment: if you have anther question, you should accept this answer and post the new question, the question in the comment is poorly formed and hard to read

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer if you can show me how to get the Url that you inputed in your code. I tried looking through Google to find the method and couldn't find anything..