# Finding out how to get this specific URL

Tags: json, web-scraping

In another question a user used [this url(1)](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=aapl&ops=clear) which contains a data table and somehow converted the code into [this url(2)](http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t=XNAS:aapl&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=378724&callback=jsonp1482077238548&_=1482077239651) in order to scrape using json and beautiful soup.

My question is how do you get the second url which is scrape friendly given the first url?

The user which somehow got the 2nd url was asked how he got it and it has been a while and he never responded..Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157191/extracting-numbers-from-yahoo-financial-statement-willing-to-pay-some-money-thr) to the original thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using Google Chrome Developer Tools (and with other browsers as well).

1. Open **Google Chrome browser** and navigate to the first [URL](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=aapl&ops=clear)
2. Open **Developer Tools** (⌘ + option + i)
3. Head to "**Network**" tab
4. Click on "**Preserve log**" and on "**XHR**" (since it's an XMLHttpRequest)
   [image]
5. Reload the page and you'll see the **XMLHttpRequest** to the second [URL](http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=796325&callback=jsonp1482278335865&_=1482278335938)
   [image]

**Note:** In this case I guessed that it was loaded by an XHR but I'd recommend to click "All" instead of "XHR" next time. You'll see more results and you'll need to filter and/or take some more time to find the call/request on the matter, but it'll be more accurate.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Do you know if there is a way to automate the process within python to get that url?

Comment: Thing is, we usually do this (studying the site) before we build a scraper and that is because that call to that particular URL could be anywhere in the whole HTML (including src to other JavaScripts). So I think that couldn't be automated. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this is completely off topic from the original question so you don't have to answer,  but since it can't be automated I was wondering if you could recommend a way to scrape the data table of the first url?